# Unity null on generated object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

In Unity C# I want to highlight a Hex. In theory it should work with

```
    board[x, y].objectonhex = new PawnClass(...);
    if(board[x, y].objectonhex != null)
```

but the result is: null. I Debug.Log(objecthex) already and the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqNL0.png) is not normal. Before applying a new Object it is Null and then null. I already tried other methods of testing if it is null like: Equals(null) etc. (is null does not work either in C# 4.0)

Here is the full code:

```
public void ShowOn()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        for (int y = 0 + x % 2; y <= size * 2; y += 2)
            if (board[x, y].objectonhex != null)
                Debug.Log(x + "|||" + y);
}

public void Test()
{
    Debug.Log(board[5, 11].objectonhex);
    board[5, 11].objectonhex = new PawnClass.Character(0, "SS", UniqueID.alien, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 3, 1, 1, 5);
    Debug.Log(board[5, 11].objectonhex);

    board[5, 9].objectonhex = new PawnClass.Character(0, "SB", UniqueID.nazi, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 2, 1, 1, 5);
    board[7, 3].objectonhex = new PawnClass.Character(0, "SU", UniqueID.alien, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 3, 1, 1, 5);

    ShowOn();
    //highLight(board[5, 11]);
}
```

Comment: Could you show us where and how do you declare the `board` field ?

Comment: Hex[,] board = new Hex[20, 40]

Comment: Can you show the code containing the pawnclass and it's Character field?